# List all column element names

Tags: r, names

Possibly it is an easy problem. I have a dataset like the following.

```
dat2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  De  Ep  Ti  ID1
A1123    A117 A121 A100 A11231
                   A1123 A108 C207 D110 E11232
                   A1124 A122 C207 D110 E11232
                   A1124 A117 C207 D110 E11232
                   A1124 A122 C208 D110 E11232
                   B1125 A108 C208 D110 E11232
                   B1125 A108 C208 D110 E11232
                   B1126 A122 C208 D110 E11233
                   C1126 A109 C208 D111 E11233
                   ")
dat2
dat2
     ID   De   Ep   Ti    ID1
1 A1123 A117 A121 A100 A11231
2 A1123 A108 C207 D110 E11232
3 A1124 A122 C207 D110 E11232
4 A1124 A117 C207 D110 E11232
5 A1124 A122 C208 D110 E11232
6 B1125 A108 C208 D110 E11232
7 B1125 A108 C208 D110 E11232
8 B1126 A122 C208 D110 E11233
9 C1126 A109 C208 D111 E11233
```

I can get summary by using `table` function.

```
table(dat2$ID)
A1123 A1124 B1125 C1126 
    2     3     3     1 

table(dat2$De)
A108 A109 A117 A122 
   3    1    2    3
```

I want to list all element names in first two columns like the following.

```
t <- c("A1123", "A1124","B1125","C1126", "A108", "A109", "A117", "A122")
t
[1] "A1123" "A1124" "B1125" "C1126" "A108"  "A109"  "A117"  "A122"
```

Based on quick response from Neal, I can get the list of first two columns easily.

```
with(dat2, union(ID, De))
[1] "A1123" "A1124" "B1125" "C1126" "A117"  "A108"  "A122"  "A109"
```

But if I want to get list of names from all columns, then the above is code not working.

Comment: Are all your columns, indeed, "factor"s? Then, I guess, the most efficient you could do is to concatenate the `levels` from each column.

Comment: I edited the data. In fact, all are factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use union to find unique values in two sets:

```
with(dat2, union(ID, De))
```

For all columns, use Reduce:

```
Reduce(union, dat2)
```

Comment: Pretty quick and works perfectly.

Comment: I have changed the question slightly. To get the list of all element names from all columns `union` function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to get the unique values for the whole dataframe is:

```
unique(unlist(dat2))
```

which gives:

```
> unique(unlist(dat2))
 [1] A1123  A1124  B1125  B1126  C1126  A117   A108   A122   A109   A121  
[11] C207   C208   A100   D110   D111   A11231 E11232 E11233
18 Levels: A1123 A1124 B1125 B1126 C1126 A108 A109 A117 A122 A121 C207 ... E11233
```

---

If you want a count for each unique values, you can use:

```
table(unlist(dat2))
```

which results in:

```
 A1123  A1124  B1125  B1126  C1126   A108   A109   A117   A122   A121   C207 
     2      3      2      1      1      3      1      2      3      1      3 
  C208   A100   D110   D111 A11231 E11232 E11233 
     5      1      7      1      1      6      2
```